# How to unit test device specific functions for hybrid app development e.g LocalFileSystem

Tags: cordova, unit-testing

I'm building a hybrid app using ionic (although I think for this question any cordova based development could suffice as a valid example) and am currently unit testing using Karma, Jasmine and PhantomJS.

During my testing I've come across a few of my functions which access the `LocalFileSystem` for storage and I am wondering if there is any way to test access to this. With the compatible browsers for Karma, there doesn't seem to be anything I could use, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `browser` as a target platform in cordova !
Common cordova plugins (for example cordova-plugin-file or corvoda-plugin-file-transfer) has support for browser too (some of them are only there
for testing stuff of course!). This is possible because with HTML5 your browser can access quite the same functionalities of a mobile device (FileSystem API, access to Camera, geolocation, GPU access, notification api etc...).
So the only thing you have to do is:

`cordova platform add browser`